# PIctureBox/Rectangle is not display when size increase

Tags: c#, bitmap, size, picturebox

I am trying to display different parts of a single picture multiple times (15 pieces) on a form. I store each piece as a `Rectangle`, convert it to a `BitMap`, and then add that BitMap to a my Tile object, which is `PixtureBox` object. When I do the following, without inflating the size is displays like so in the first image: (code included)[image: without inflating]:

But when I try inflating it (line 157), only 4 of the images show,like so:[image: with inflating]

am I approaching this incorrectly?

If it helps, the original picture is just an image of the number 1 and I want each piece to pretty much fill up 4 times the amount in the first image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better Method would be to resize the bitmap itself and assigning parts of it to the rectangle.

and for performance .. Instead of creating the bitmap every time .. store it in a stream and access the same stream every time .. this will save you a lot of processing power .. though might not be much significant given your small app and a powerful processor

Comment: When I try changing the size of the width/height for the clone I get an error stating that its read only...Im changing it by clone.Height = h;

Comment: Nvm, I figured it out! Thanks!